# Problem accessing elements by class or ID

Tags: html, ruby, rubygems, watir

I have to access a div collection and extrapolate some data cycling through it.

```
names = b.divs(class:"item ng-final")

names.each do |name|
    data = name.text
    puts data
end
```

It grabs correctly the collection ("puts names" output is indeed a div collection), but it doesn't start the cycle ("puts names.length" is 0).
The only thing I can think of is that the website is built using angular and every element has also an ng-class.

Does this create conflict in Watir?

Comment: There shouldn't be a conflict. It might help to share the HTML of the page so we can validate that the locator is correct. Assuming the locator is correct, you might want to check some of the common issues - eg element is in an iframe or shadow DOM.

Comment: Thank you! The element is located correctly, I checked many times, but it seems that it's hidden, like you said.

Comment: For example if I print the html with the method browser.html it doesn't show up.

Comment: If you open the browser developer tools, is the element in an iframe or the shadow DOM?

Comment: Yes it is indeed in an iframe! I resolved using browser.iframe, thank you!